# Test case not running iin selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I tried to use the following code to open a URL in my local system. But I get error message as shown in screen shot.

**Code**

```
package First_test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class first_case {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

                //Launch the Website
                driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000");

                // Print a Log In message to the screen
                System.out.println("Successfully opened the website ");


                // Close the driver
                driver.quit();

    }

}
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PegPh.png)

What shall I do to solve this problem? Thanx!

Comment: Use geckodriver and code mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install gecko driver. A brief introduction about it and how to install gecko driver can be found in following link. Hope this helps!

**Gecko Driver is the link between your tests in Selenium and the Firefox browser**

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/how-to-use-geckodriver/

Answer (score 0):

I installed gecko driver from github and put it in the folder location of my workplace and it worked!

[working result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Azy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Download geckodriver and use this code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:/software and tools/geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
//Launch the Website
driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
// Print a Log In message to the screen
System.out.println("Successfully opened the website ");
// Close the driver
 driver.quit();
```